# Logged client IP in logon events in SQL Server 2016 is NULL for remote connections

Tags: sql-server, audit

I have an on-premise SQL Server 2016 that I want to audit actions done on it. I got [sqlaudit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/write-sql-server-audit-events-to-the-security-log?view=sql-server-ver15) logs and [extended events logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/quick-start-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) but none of them log the IP of the remote client that connects to the database.

I tried to create a trigger that inserts this data into a table I created, using [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eventdata-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), and came up with this:

```
CREATE TABLE login_log_database (PostTime datetime, DB_User nvarchar(100), Event nvarchar(100), ClientHost nvarchar(2000));  
GO 

CREATE TRIGGER log   
ON all server
FOR LOGON   
AS  
DECLARE @data XML  
SET @data = EVENTDATA()  
INSERT login_log   
   VALUES   
   (GETDATE(),   
   CONVERT(nvarchar(100), CURRENT_USER),   
   @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)'),   
   @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ClientHost)[1]', 'nvarchar(2000)') ) ;  
GO
```

But when I connect to my database from a generic JDBC client (DBeaver specifically) the entries in the table the Event field and the ClientHost are "NULL". Connecting locally from SSMS on the machine itself the Event field is LOGON and the Client Host is "local machine".

Am I doing something wrong with reading values from the XML somehow?

Comment: you could always use the client_net_address of the connection property (unless the client connects with named pipes or locally from the server with shared memory):
select CONNECTIONPROPERTY ('client_net_address')

Comment: @lptr I ran select * from sys.dm_exec_connections; (as the sa user) and it only returned 10 lines. Tried to open a new remote JDBC connection - the connection was not logged to this table.

Comment: just replace the whole @data.value(..ClientHost) line in the trigger with CONNECTIONPROPERTY ('client_net_address')

Comment: @lptr that works, thanks a bunch!
Can you add this as an official answer so I can upvote it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use CONNECTIONPROPERTY('client_net_address'), to capture the ip address of the client.

> caveat: client_net_address does not return the ip when the client connects via shared memory or named pipe.
>
> for shared memory `<local machine>` is returned
>
> for named pipes `<named pipe>` is returned

```
INSERT login_log   
   VALUES   
   (GETDATE(),   
   CONVERT(nvarchar(100), CURRENT_USER),   
   @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)'),   
   CONNECTIONPROPERTY('client_net_address') ) ;
```